# Найти и добавить объект по переменной

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне необходимо добавить scriptable object в лист объектов, если одна из его переменных (ID) будет равна значению другой переменной.

Сейчас у меня сериализуется ID каждого предмета из инвентаря как float в массив, но вот как при десериализации всех ID мне по их значению заполнить List скриптейбл объектами идентичными по значению переменной (мне нужно именно найти и добавить объект с идентичным ID как в массиве, десериализация уже есть)

Comment: Если предметы это `ScriptableObject`, что бы избежать коллизии `ID`, используй их собственные `GetInstanceID()`, которые есть у каждого `UnityEngine.Object` и не повторяются. Для объектов сцены они не постоянные, а для ассетов в каталогах проекта постоянные.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нашел решение в интернете. отказался от ID предметов, вызываю их по названию, так как показано на скрине